# Running a short script fails with exit code 1

Tags: bash, github-actions

I have following fragment in my github action:

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- run: grep resolved package-lock.json | grep -q example.com && echo "package-lock.json contains invalid entries" && exit 1
  shell: bash --noprofile --norc {0}
  name: Validate package-lock.json file
```

But it fails, first I thought it was issue with pipefail so I provide now my own template above, but I still get error:

```
Run grep resolved package-lock.json | grep -q example.com && echo "package-lock.json contains invalid entries" && exit 1
  grep resolved package-lock.json | grep -q example.com && echo "package-lock.json contains invalid entries" && exit 1
  shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc {0}
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I validated that this one-liner works fine when I execute it in my bash, so why it doesn't when on github action?

Comment: Because the exit code from `grep` is a failure if it doesn't find anything.

Comment: @tripleee yeah, I was so sure that error is in actions that I failed to remember that, thanks